# file.listFiles() NullPointerException on build jar

Tags: java

When I run my code on Intellij Idea it work perfectly but when I run my code on the .jar (so build) there is a NullPointerException. Did someone know why and how to fix this ?

```
File folder = new 
File(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("assets/maps/").getPath());
System.out.println(folder);
System.out.println(folder.listFiles());
for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
    if(file.getName().endsWith(".btdm"))
    maps.add(getMap(file));
}
```

console :

```
file:\E:\Programmation\BabyTD\out\artifacts\BabyTD_jar\BabyTD.jar!\assets\maps
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at fr.picearth.Main.getMaps(Main.java:51)
at fr.picearth.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `folder` is not a folder or cannot be accessed for some reason (including the fact that `java.io.File` cannot open jar or other zip files like ordinary folders), then [`listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) will return null. You've already seen this in your print out. You have to check prior to iterating:

```
File[] files = folder.listFiles();
if (files != null)
    for (File file : files)
        if(file.getName().endsWith(".btdm"))
            maps.add(getMap(file));
```

However, you probably want to work with [`java.util.zip.ZipFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) instead

Comment: Thanks, but can ZipFile list the files in my ressource ? Because all the getRessource() works well there is juste here that I can't list the files.

Comment: @Chokearth: Loading resources from the classpath is an entirely different beast from using the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `assets/maps/` folder is part of your jar file, then you won't be able to access like any other folder on your drive. 
IDE consider it as folder/file on drive so it works with `getResource`.

What you could do is to use getResourceAsStream() method with the directory path, and the input Stream will have all the files name from that dir.

try `getResourceAsStream` inplace of `getResource`

```
String respath = "/path_to_file";

InputStream in = sample2.class.getResourceAsStream(respath);

if ( in == null ){

    throw new Exception("resource not found: " + respath);
}

InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");

int len;

char cbuf[] = new char[2048];

while ((len = inr.read(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length)) != -1) {
    // do something with cbuf
}
```

EDIT 2 :

if you are using java 7+ then you can also use

```
 private Path getFolderPath() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    URI uri = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("folder").toURI();
    if ("jar".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
      FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.emptyMap(), null);
      return fileSystem.getPath("path/to/folder/inside/jar");
    } else {
      return Paths.get(uri);
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand how use an InputStream to list my file.

Comment: The first methode work on Intellij Idea but not on .jar (nothing list). And the second I don't realy see how that can help me to list my file. I think I will add all the file that interest me in a list, it'll probably be more easy T_T. Thanks to trying

Comment: one more workaround ( though not proper design ) to package your resources as separate folder and not as part of jar and then your IDE code will be able to read it using absolute path.